# how to run flows in classic url even if "Run Flows with a Lightning Skin" is enabled?

Tags: lightning-experience, visual-workflow, winter17, salesforce-classic

I have created a flow on one of my environment and I am calling that flow on custom button by providing correct url. Now problem is when i click on the button,the url is referring Lightning url rather than salesforce url.
I have checked the process automation setting and found that "Enable Lightning Runtime for Flows" is enabled.I have disabled the setting and flows now refer classic url.

But when I enable this option and run the flows in classic UI then it display below message:
[image]

It is not returning url that was returned in classic UI.

I have to manually click on back button and see my changes.Not sure what needs to be done here..

Comment: Have you looked at the controller for your flow(s) to see what the finish URL is for them?

Comment: @crmprogdev below are the url of the custom button:
**/flow/UpdateProductCompetitor?OpportunityId={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}**
so when I click on button,ideally it just refresh the page navigate back to Opportunity record but If I checked "Enable Lightning Runtime for Flows" then it just display the message as Flow finished that I mentioned in my screenshot but do not navigate back to Opportunity record.I did not face this issue a month before.Looks like my org has installed Winter 17 updates that could be the reason it opens flows in lightning.

Comment: Might want to try adding "no override=true" to that retURL string.

Comment: I've seen a few posts indicating that retUrl is not working in flows w lightning runtime enabled.  Haven't dug into it yet but will update w links to success when I'm back at a desk.

Comment: Here is a thread on success that is indicating it's an issue.  No known issue posted, just an idea.  https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00002yRgUB

Comment: @gorav So this is actually an issue.The only workaround I am able to see here is to create a VF page and call it in Custom Button which increases the design.But anyways I have raised a case with salesforce to see if there is any other workaround than VF & disabling the seeting 'Enable Lightning Runtime for Flows'.Will update you soon on this.

Comment: @crmprogdev How can I add "no override=true" in return url because I am assigning Opportunity ID at the same time.

Comment: @crmprogdev Custom button that I created is on related list of Opportunity not on Opportunity Layout. I created a VF page and in the URL I am trying pass VF page like this **/apex/UpdateCompetitor?Id={!Opportunity.Id}&OpportunityId={!Opportunity.Id}** but it does not work.

Comment: If it's going to work, you should be able to add `&no%20override=true` at the end of your querystring.

Comment: @crmprogdev It does not work.It display the same page that was displayed earlier in my screenshot.Below is the url it returns when launching in lightning experience:
**flowruntime/runtime.app?flowDevName=UpdateProductCompetitor&arguments=%5B%7B%27label%27%3A%27OpportunityId%27%2C%27dataType%27%3A%27String%27%2C%27value%27%3A"0069E000001uGxQ"%7D%5D&no+override=true&retURL=%2F0069E000001uGxQ&OpportunityId=0069E000001uGxQ**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After raising the case with salesforce,instead of providing me the possible workaround they have just provided the bug number 'W-327172'.After doing some analysis I have found possible workaround that works both in classic as well as lightning.We need to create a VF page that calls visual flows and in VF we have to mention the return url.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >
    <flow:interview name="Mention_Flow_Name" finishLocation="/{!Opportunity.Id}">
        <apex:param name="OpportunityId" value="{!Opportunity.Id}" />
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

In my requirement I have to create custom button on Related List Object not on parent object.In Current Salesforce Design,You can not call VF page when Button Type is List Button.So I have Used the below syntax and Bingooo,it works perfectly fine in my Case:

```
/apex/UpdateCompetitor?Id={!Opportunity.Id}&OpportunityId={!Opportunity.Id}
```

I have confirmed this syntax with Salesforce Tier 3 Agent.As per them,it is a valid syntax that you can use to solve this kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as per Salesforce design. retURL won't work in Lightning Flow.

Comment: So what is the workaround?